# Display random friend list from Facebook user

Tags: php, facebook

I am looking for advice. I want to get random friends from a user, I have this code but it displays all users. How to display only 20 random users?

```
$ret=$facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friends=$ret['data'];
for($i=0;$i<count($friends);$i++) {
      $friend=$friends[$i];
  echo "{$friend['name']}\n";
}
```

Comment: Put friends into an array, shuffle it, and take the first 20 out of the array afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an FQL call using `RAND` and `LIMIT`

`SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) order by rand() limit 20`

This should give you a set of 20 random friends

Or with your call you change it to

```
$ret=$facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friends=$ret['data'];
$rand_keys = array_rand($friends, 20);

for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
      $friend=$friends[$rand_keys[$i]];
  echo "{$friend['name']}\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php